# Modern DNS load-balancing solutions

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, load-balancing

I'm learning distributes systems and now I'm researching the DNS load-balancing topic.

I have few Linux servers and I want to setup next configuration:

1. one DNS load-balancer that resolves IP address of less loaded server;
2. several application servers that process user requests and send own load statistics to DNS load-balancer.

I have googled for a while and found the [lbnamed](http://www.stanford.edu/~riepel/lbnamed/) that seems to be built according to [dlbDNS](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3345) idea and do what I need. What I'm confused with it that it seems to be stalled for a while (no updates since 2006) though there is remarks that it has few issues. Also I was unable to find any other solutions. So I thought that maybe I'm googling a wrong thing, or maybe such functionality is included into some wide spread application like bind.

So my question is: is DNS load-balancing approach is actual nowadays and what modern solutions (applications) can be used?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the DNS based load balancing is not as much applied to clusters within a single data centre but more often used to point users to geographically nearby instances of an application.

The problem with DNS is that records are cached, often longer then the TTL even, meaning that when you update the configuration of your cluster, and the DNS, clients may still be directed to an inactive/unresponsive node.

That means that a progressively smaller fraction of your users will experience transient problems for as long as it takes for their DNS cache to be purged.

That can be completely acceptable or not. It also depends on if your application is public oron the corporate intranet and your clients are for instance exclusively using Active Directory domain controllers as the DNS servers.

The second possible problem with DNS load balancing is that Numerous users can be using a single caching name server so the number of DNS queries your name server receives has potentially no bearing on the number of requests coming your way.

So no, in your case you're better off with layer3, network load balancing or possibly something like HAproxy rather then DNS load balancing.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would never use DNS based loadbalancing. Most important reason is that there are too many misbehaving resolvers at ISP's and on the client's machine. These resolvers can for example ignore TTL's thus caching DNS answers and potentially give back incorrect answers. Since you're not able to properly influence these things, I'd rather not depend on them to have loadbalancing working properly.

All loadbalancing setups I've seen (F5, A10, and open source tools like keepalived) do loadbalancing of TCP-sessions (or UDP, ICMP).

Comment: Both F5 and A10 have DNS load balancing appliances for GeoIP purposes, GTM and GSLB respectively.

Answer (score 0):

"load-balancing" although historically not "true" balancing, these days, dns based load balancing is a necessary and very effective part (first tier) of a high volume, high availability solution.

the dns layer is able to resolve a dns name to the client based on their geographic location (GeoIP), thereby shaving a few hundred ms's from response time.

this was not possible even a few years ago, when dns load-balancing, or poor man's balancing, meant a single dns A record with multiple IPs.  those IPs, were not even load balancers in and of themselves (like you see today running CARP/VRRP/HSRP/etc), but they were the actual end point web servers!!!!  with this model, any one server going down results in a fraction of all traffic being black holed.

today's use of sophisicated dns, as its own HA tier, is very effective.  an example of this is aws route53, which uses a non-rfc complient "A/ALIAS" record, to tie top level domains to ELB's for massive scalability and uptime.  (no, i dont work for aws)  however, there are several other providers that will resolve your dns to clients requests, based on the clients closest datacenter that can service the request.

> http://dyn.com/managed-dns/
>
> http://aws.amazon.com/route53/